# Observable<Observable<GridDataResult>> vs Observable<GridDataResult> in kendo UI for angular

Tags: angular, observable, karma-jasmine, kendo-ui-angular2

kendo UI for angular uses `Observable<Observable<GridDataResult>>` as return type for grid data

```
  getData(model: State): Observable<Observable<GridDataResult>> {
return this.mainService.post(`http://localhost:41689/api/Data/GetData`, model);
}
```

then to call this

```
  public view: Observable<GridDataResult> | undefined;
  public gridState: State = {
  sort: [],
  skip: 0,
  take: 10
  };

public getData() {
return this.sampleTypeService.getData(this.gridState).subscribe(
  res => {
    this.view = res;
  }
);
}
```

this works . but in unit test I cannot get data in `view` because it is an observable.

if I change

```
public view: Observable<GridDataResult> | undefined;
```

to

```
public view: GridDataResult | undefined;
```

and getData to

```
getData(model: State): Observable<GridDataResult> {
return this.mainService.post(`http://localhost:41689/api/Data/GetData`, model);
}
```

it works. And now I can do unit testing on returned data.

I want to know what is the difference between these two

Comment: `Observable<any> != Observable<Observable<any>>` - what confuses you here?

Comment: @Antoniossss in what cases we should use `Observable<Observable<any>>` ? if we use it how we can test its data?

Comment: I never had to use `Observable<Observable<any>>` but thats probably my case.